# Metadata Navigation in Docment Set

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, document-set, metadata-navigation, classic-experience

I have set Metadata Navigation in a SharePoint site (Classic Experience).

It works well in all document libraries, it works when I open a Folder in these document libraries but it disappears when I open a document set present in these document libraries.

Is it possible to enable Metadata Navigation in document sets?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is by default that metadata navigation cannot be used in a Document Set.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but now I wonder why: in Folder it works and Document Set derives from Folder, like their IDs show: 0x0120 -> **0x0120**D520 , can you explain me why? Is there a technical motivation (such as, for example, for the List View Threshold)?